# Access to value from decorator(typescript)

Tags: typescript

```
export class UploadGreetingController {
constructor(
private greetingFacade: GreetingFacade,

) {}
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
    storage: diskStorage({
        destination: (req: any, file, cb) => {
            if (process.env.DEVELOPMENT === 'prod') {
                return cb(null, `${process.env.DEV_PATH_TO_GREETING_AUDIO}`);
            }
            return cb(null, `${process.env.PROD_PATH_TO_GREETING_AUDIO}`);
        },
        filename: async (req: any, file, cb) => {
            let uuid = await v4();
            req.params.uuid = uuid;
            return cb(null, `${uuid}.mp3`);
        }
    }),
    fileFilter: async (req, file: any, cb) => {
        let {userId, accountId} = req.user;
        let {greetingID} = req.params;
        if (greetingID === 'null' || !greetingID) {
            req.params.error = 'greeting:youShouldPassGreetingID';
            return cb(null, false);
        }
//HERE I WANT TO GET ACCESS TO this.greetingFacade .How can I make it ?
            let greetingEntity: any = await this.greetingFacade.getGreetingByUserIdAndAccountIdAndGreetingID(userId, accountId, greetingID);
            let type = (req.params.type) ? req.params.type : greetingEntity.type;
            if (type) {
                let type = (typeof req.params.type === 'string') ? parseInt(req.params.type) : req.params.type;
                if (type === 2) {
                    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(mp3)$/)) {
                        return cb(null, false);
                    }
                    req.params.error = 'greeting:youShouldPassCorrectAudioFormat';
                    let deleteGreeting = (greetingEntity.uuid) ?
                        await this.greetingFacade.deleteAudioFromDisk(`${process.env.DEV_PATH_TO_GREETING_AUDIO}`, greetingEntity.uuid) : null;
                    return cb(null, file);
                }
                return cb(null, false);
            }
            return cb(null, false);
        }
    }))
}
```

Above u can see my code. I want to get access to `this.greetingFacade` value. But inside `@UseInterceptors` of this decorator it is invisible. How to make it visible( or get access to this value)? It isn't a problem if I don't need to use this `private greetingFacade: GreetingFacade`this part of a code. But in my case can't make it. Check this snippet of code.

```
  //HERE I WANT TO GET ACCESS TO this.greetingFacade .How can I make it ?
```

Comment: are u able to resolve the dependency  inside constructor itself??

Comment: try like this greetingFacade:GreetingFacade;
    export class UploadGreetingController {
    constructor(
    private greetingFacade: GreetingFacade,
    
    ) {
    this.greetingFacade=greetingFacade;
    }

Comment: greetingFacade:GreetingFacade; this line after constructor ? maybe let greetingFacade:GreetingFacade ??

Comment: Can u send me response pls. how it have to be

Comment: I hope you are not using AngularJS , the code looks like so.

Comment: You can't use let because that variable is gloabal. the current code will work without any compilation issue , you can use the access modifier(updated the code)

Comment: I can't declare it like u send me in typescript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178481/discussion-between-andrey-radkevich-and-jemi).

Answer (score 1):

Just declare a property on your class or controller and set the instance to the property inside constructor.

```
  private greetingFacade:GreetingFacade;

    export class UploadGreetingController {
    constructor(greetingFacade: GreetingFacade) {

    this.greetingFacade=greetingFacade;

    }
```